# Versión específica de JQuery para bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Cuándo añado la versión de jquery 3.2.1 de forma local me marca un error el archivo bootstrap.js, pero si añado jquery con enlace CDN no me marca ningún error, la pregunta es... ¿Es por la versión de jquery, hay una versión específica de jquery para bootstrap 4?

Comment: según la propia documentación con la 3.2.1 basta https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Es lo que tengo entendido pero, cuándo cargo el archivo jquery de forma local me marca un error, y con CDN no.

Comment: añade entonces en tu pregunta la muestra del HTML donde lo estas incluyendo para ver que pudiera ser